# Spark scala cannot find file type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using the Spark Scala api in Databricks.
Trying to follow along: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-avro.html

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema

val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("episode.avsc"))
```

Throws error: not found: type File

Where is this file type? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was aliasing. Solved as per: http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/01/exclude-style-import-semantics.html

```
import java.io.{File=>jfile}
val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new jfile("episode.avsc"))
```

Leaving the question up for visibility